# i get ths error : string index out of range

Tags: python

i want to know the difference

When i run this code

```
message = "Three can keep a secret, if two of them are dead."
translated = ""
i  = len(message)
while i >= 0:
    translated = translated + message[i]
    i = i - 1
print translated
```

i get error :

IndexError: string index out of range

when i changed it to :

```
message = "Three can keep a secret, if two of them are dead."
translated = ""
i  = len(message) - 1 
while i >= 0:
    translated = translated + message[i]
    i = i - 1
print translated
```

it works now but why !???

Why i must type len(massage) - 1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes start from 0. The index of the first element is `0`.

So the index of last element is ... (facepalm).

Comment: len("apple")                                                                                                                  the result:                                                                                                           5

Comment: and i can send you screen if you don't believe me :( so the first element is 1 as the result :(

Comment: The length is 5, but your indices would be 0,1,2,3,4.

Comment: whenever in doubt, come up with an example, as @AndyHasIt did. That way you can verify that your math is OK. The shorter, the better: len("a") = 1, last element is at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Take a short string, like `str = "hello"`, it is made of 5 characters.

```
str[0] is 'h'
srt[1] is 'e'
...
srt[4] is 'o'
str[5] does not exist!
```

That's why you can only go up to len(str)-1, the index starts from 0, not 1.